# Creating Custom compound Type in Hippo CMS10 and using it inside document

Tags: hippocms

I have  Created Compound type Profile under go-green project of hippo community version. I have created compound-type inside go-green document types. This compound type has 5 fields via `Name`, `Title`, `Designation`, `Description` and `Image`. I wanna know how to render this compound type in the document where I am using this compound type. I have written my bean class for this compound type, but unable to render it inside document.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The bean and the template need to be tied together. There is a third component which is the java Component class which needs to load the document on to the request. Though, if extending an existing document it probably is already put on the request. Then you can use the bean in your template like any other java bean.

Some of our tutorials may help. They start here[1].

[1] https://www.onehippo.org/trails/deep-dive/hello-world.html

--edit--

I should've read more carefully.

You shouldn't create a bean for a compound but for a document. This bean already exists for the document types in the project. If you are using essentials you can use the Bean Writer tool. Otherwise you will need to create the bean for the whole document. This still needs to be put on the request by a component of course. The class itself should be in your site war. It will be found as long as it is on the class path.